# Test automation tool for Flash Games [Windows,Mac]

Tags: flash, testing, automation

I'm looking for a tool that helps to automate front end of the flash games, meaning that it enables user to record a macro (while playing a game or its part), log flash errors/messages, allow custom scripting.

I found Ranorex, Selenium, Watir, iMacros and Ranorex seems to be the most advanced but it cannot run on Mac, and I'm looking for a tool that runs on mac and win.

My goal is to automate testing of the flash games. If anyone knows such tool, I'd really appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Adobe UI scripter
It is Open source 
http://sourceforge.net/adobe/genie/wiki2/FAQ/

But it only works with AS3.

Answer (score 1):

I found Sikuli-a tool that can automate everything, including flash games and it's cross platform (java) and open source. Scripts can be written in python.

Answer (score 0):

you can look for Genie tool, which open source and easy to automate AS3 Games.
refer : http://sourceforge.net/adobe/genie/wiki/Home/

Comment: May be you should explain a bit...